# Single variable algebraic equation can be solved by multiple values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I solved x(x-1) = 0 like so:

$$ \left(\frac {1}{x}\right) * x(x-1)=0 * \left(\frac1x\right) $$
$$ x-1 = 0$$
$$ (1) + x-1 = 0 + (1)$$
$$ x=1 $$

The correct answer is x = 1 and x = 0,  where did I mess up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, we can't eliminate the variable $x$ as the given equation $x(x-1)=0$ or $x^2-x=0$ is a quadratic equation in terms of $x$ hence it has two roots which are found (also by quadratic formula) as follows $$x(x-1)=0$$ $$x=0\ \text{&}\ \ x-1=0$$
$$x=0\ \text{&}\ \ x=1$$

Answer (score 3):

The step where you divide by $x$ requires $x$ to be non-zero, since it isn't possible to divide by $0$. So, at that step, you are removing the $x=0$ solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve these is to divide both sides by your non zero factors which are x, x-1. Then you get: 
Case 1: divide both sides by x:
$$x(x-1)=0$$
$$\frac1x*x (x-1)=\frac0x$$
$$x-1=0$$
$$x=1$$

Case 2: divide both sides by (x-1)
$$x(x-1)=0$$
$$\frac1{x-1}*x (x-1)=\frac0{x-1}$$
$$x=0$$

Therefore you have two answers: x=0,1